# TFF loading a pre-trained Keras model

Tags: tensorflow-federated

My goal is to load a base model from a .hdf5 file (it's a Keras model), and continue to train it with federated learning. Here is how I initialize the base model for FL:

```
def model_fn():
    model = tf.keras.load_model(path/to/model.hdf5)
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(model=model, 
                                         dummy_batch=db, 
                                         loss=loss, 
                                         metrics=metrics)

trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)
state = trainer.initialize()
```

However, it seems like the resulting state.model weights are randomly initialized, and are different from my saved model. When I evaluate the model's performance even before any federated training, it performs as a randomly initialized model: 50% accuracy. Here's how I evaluate the performance:

```
def evaluate(state):
    keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path/to/model.hdf5, compile=False)
    tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(keras_model, state.model)
    keras_model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    return keras_model.evaluate(features, values)
```

How can I initialize a tff model with the saved model weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is expected that `initialize` would rerun the initializers, and return this value.

However, there is a way to do such a thing with TFF. TFF is strongly typed and functional--if we can construct an argument with the correct values which matches the type expected by your federated averaging process above, things should "just work". So the goal here will be to *construct* an argument satisfying these requirements.

You can look to the [`FileCheckpointManager's` load implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/359f872bfdf2fa94375bac9f106251f20a1e675b/tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py#L164) for a little inspiration here, but I think you are in a simpler case with Keras.

Assuming you have your hands on `state` like above and `model` your Keras model, there is a shortcut to unpacking and repacking everything here--as indicated in [this section](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation#fine-tune_the_model_with_federated_learning) of one of TFF's tutorials--that is, the usage of [`tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/state_with_new_model_weights). If you have state and model as above (and TF is in eager mode), the following should work for you:

```py
state = tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights(
    state,
    trainable_weights=[v.numpy() for v in model.trainable_weights],
    non_trainable_weights=[
        v.numpy() for v in model.non_trainable_weights
    ])
```

This should reassign your model's weights to the appropriate elements of the `state` object.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a promising start. But do you know how to resolve the resulting error: 

"The target structure is of type '<class 'TensorFlow_federated.python.common_libs.anonymous_tuple.AnonymousTuple'>'. However the input structure is a sequence (<class 'lists'>) of length 6. Nest cannot guarantee that it is safe to map one to the other."

Comment: Also, I'm confused why my original method didn't work. It seems to work in this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation#fine-tune_the_model_with_federated_learning

Comment: you must convert `state`

Comment: @Eliza How do I convert it?

Comment: `state ` in your example is an instance of  `tff.python.common_libs.anonymous_tuple.AnonymousTuple ` (IIRC), which is not compatible with tf.convert_to_tensor, as is needed by save_checkpoint and declared in its docstring. The general solution often used in TFF research code is to introduce a Python  `attr `s class to convert away from the anonymous tuple as soon as state is returned

Comment: Eliza is correct here--but there is a different way around this. Edited the answer above--I didn't know we had such a function prerolled in `tff.learning`. You were looking at the correct tutorial--but perhaps it is unclear that it is not the *cloning* of the model which results in this behavior, but rather the reassigning to `state`.

Comment: @KeithRush I try your solution of `tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights` but I find this error : `NameError: name 'model' is not defined` can you tell me here model is what ?

Comment: Is it possible that your model has a different name? `keras_model` maybe?

Comment: Hello @KeithRush, Thanks brother I try this solution but for me it still same problem : accuracy = 0.5 and never increase !!