# How to transfer weights from baseline model to federated model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

```
def create_keras_model():
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.load_weights('/content/drive/My Drive/localmodel/weights')
return model
```

Tried something like this in Colab, but I get errno 21, is a directory.

Then I tried another method as shown below,

```
tff_model = create_keras_model() #now this function doesnt load weights, just returns a Sequential model   
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(tff_model, model_with_weights)
```

Just like assign_weights_to_keras_model() transfers weights from tff_model to keras model, I want to transfer weights from keras model to tff_model. How can this be done?

Comment: *Re: errno 21*: `model.load_weights` is calling [`tf.keras.Model.load_weights()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) and it seems like it might be pointing at a path that was not generated by the paired [`tf.keras.Model.save_weights()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights)?

Comment: Not really. Am sure its the right path.

Comment: This error is coming from the Keras library inside TF core, unrelated to TFF. It might be good to ask a question specifically about this error in the `tensorflow` tag.

Comment: Okay, I get it. And yes, I have already tagged tf. Lets hope!

Answer (score 3):

here `model_with_weights` must be a TFF value representing the weights of a model for example:

```
def model_fn():

    keras_model = create_keras_model()

  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model)

fed_avg = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, ...)
state = fed_avg.initialize()
state = fed_avg.next(state, ...)
...
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(keras_model, state.model)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ayness. But, I want to assign weights from a baseline model to a tff model, not the other way around. Lets say my baseline model gives an accuracy of 70%. I want my tff model to take it from there and start training. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

I just got to know how this can be done.
The idea is to use:

```
tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights(state, trainable_weights_numpy, non_trainable_weights_numpy)
```

[Documentation here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/state_with_new_model_weights)

where trainable weights are taken from baseline model and converted to numpy format.

```
trainable_weights = []

for weights in baseline_model.trainable_weights:
    trainable_weights.append(weights.numpy())
```

This is particularly useful when the server has part of the data and the client has similar data. May be this can be used for transfer learning.

Comment: Should have caught this earlier--see also the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786305/tff-loading-a-pre-trained-keras-model), pointing to the same solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Just had a look at it. Wish I had looked at it earlier.