# Why accuracy does not increase

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I use TFF ***0.12.0*** and I run a code of federated learning for image classification with VGG16, and here is a part of my code:

```
def create_compiled_keras_model():
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(output)
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256)(output)
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='relu')(layer1)
    model = tf.keras.Model(model.input, model_output)
    return model

def model_fn():
     keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
     return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch, loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

After running, I see that accuracy does not increase, knowing that I initialize 100 rounds.

```
round  1, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.059043884277344,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
round  2, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.059045791625977,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
round  3, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.05904769897461,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
round  4, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.059043884277344,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
round  5, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.059045791625977,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
round  6, metrics=<categorical_accuracy=0.5,loss=8.059045791625977,keras_training_time_client_sum_sec=0.0>
```

Comment: same problem !! does anyone tell us if load_model is responsible in this error ?

Comment: Can I ask what version of TFF you are using? `keras_..._sec` has been deprecated for a while now. One note I can immediately give is that TFF doesn't really ingest weights in this way; TFF treats ML models as functional, and generally the weights should be passed in as parameters. I would recommend [ModelWeights.from_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights#from_model) for initializing the weights from disk.

Comment: I use TFF 0.12.0 , give me an example please for how I use this function.. I think that it is not functional with TFF 0.12.0 !! So with what I can change it !!! Thanks

Comment: I think first we would recommend upgrading to the newest TFF (0.17 maybe?), as TFF is a young project with continual upgrades. Second, I think you've found the pointer to `state_with_new_model_weights` on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786305/tff-loading-a-pre-trained-keras-model/61789226?noredirect=1#comment113760811_61789226); i think those two things should get you fairly far